# ssh problems only when connecting from remote IP

Tags: ssh

When I try to connect from a remote computer that is not in the local network via ssh I get into trouble...

When I try to execute a TUI application it hangs and I cant do anything... I type `./menu` and then nothing happens. However this program runs with no problem when connecting with ssh with a local IP (another computer in the local network).

But this 100% same program is installed also on another computer. When connecting via ssh to the other computer with a remote IP I get no problem!

**SOLUTION**
I increased the MTU value of my router

Comment: What is TUI? Terminal User Interface? Is that the same as CLI (Command Line Interface)?

Comment: text user interface.. the old kind of programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like broken [PMTUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery). Check MTU an all involved computers and use `ping -D` to determine which maximum packet size can be transmitted over path to remote host.

Comment: the computer that works with no problem has blocked ICMP so ping doesnt work! THe other computer that has ping enabled has the problems... ping -D sends 64 byte.. i should try changing this ?

Comment: First ensure that just `ping` works. Then start trying `ping -D` with increasing packet size. Stop at the moment where answers do not come back to you, add 28 (IP+ICMP header size) to last working value to calculate actual path MTU.

Comment: -D adds timestamp... i am trying to increase packet size with -s but i dont get anything different... only the first time it says about fragmentation...